# Is there something like primary key and secondary key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, primary-key

I have something like this:

```
public class something {
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class secondsomething {
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("Sth") {get;set;}
   public int sthId{get;set;}
   public something Sth{get;set;}
}
```

And I would like to have this:

```
public class something {
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;} //keep this as primary key
   public string Name {get;set;} //maybe somehow mark this as a secondary key
}

public class secondsomething {
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("Sth") {get;set;}
   public string sthName{get;set;} //don't want the id here, but it's name
   public something Sth{get;set;}
}
```

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: There is no attribute to set in code first for unique constraint. Examine [Unique Constraint in Entity Framework Code First](http://www.it2y.info/sql-server/unique-constraint-in-entity-framework-code-first.html) article for more information.

Comment: could you provide the "create SQL" for what the Tables and their constraints and indexes might look like.

Comment: There is no support (yet) for foreign keys to unique columns other than the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the Code first migration tools useful is nominate fancy index requirements.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
HasRequired(x => x.sthName)
     .WithMany() //I assume
     .Map(x => x.MapKey("Sth"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Gert Arnold said, there is no direct support for defining indexes on Code First, but if you're using migrations you can call the Sql() method directly and define it there. Here's an example:

```
public partial class AddingUsernameIndexes : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Applications_Username ON RequestApplications (Username)");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql("DROP INDEX IX_Applications_Username");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to define multiple keys you put the [Key] and [Column(x)] properties on each.

as far as wanting the name instead of the id I do not think should be in these models.  That would be a data projection in my opinion and would be part of the query you would write against these objects.

```
SecondSomething.Where(x=>x.IsActive).Select(x=>new MyProjection { Name = x.Sth.Name, //others}).ToList();
```